# juju bootstrap key error?

Tags: juju, environment

I followed the guides the best as i could. there is some information missing like do as root or as regular user ..formatting, quotes no quotes..what the password or paraphrase for ssh should be ..couple other trivial things. that im sure add up to where im at (stuck!)

so i have a working mass server on mx-nas-01 and 3 nodes and have been trying to get juju to start. I have tried this as both root and my regular account, sudo no-sudo and here is the output i get from juju bootstrap (however i try it)
I don't know if this could be a host,domain,account issue or what i will mention i did have to shut off my dhcp server and install masq (all defaults) to get the maas pxe to work for the nodes

```
mxdog@mx-nas-01:/$ juju bootstrap
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/juju", line 8, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/control/__init__.py", line 183, in main
    env_config.load_or_write_sample()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/environment/config.py", line 229, in load_or_write_sample
    self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/environment/config.py", line 115, in load
    self.parse(file.read(), path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/environment/config.py", line 138, in parse
    config = SCHEMA.coerce(config, [])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/lib/schema.py", line 266, in coerce
    new_dict[k] = self.schema[k].coerce(v, path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/lib/schema.py", line 233, in coerce
    new_subvalue = self.value_schema.coerce(subvalue, value_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/juju/lib/schema.py", line 301, in coerce
    return self.schemas[selected].coerce(value, path)
KeyError: 'mass'
```

environments:

maas:

```
type:  mass
mass-server:  http://192.168.0.30:80/MAAS
mass-oauth:  tDRdtJeEKVARBh93eT:N5dK5HSZBsA45cBdx9:S8wMNrfkT9PeYvQN9YrnbHGxmKARv8vb
admin-secret:  ##########
default-series:  precise
```

Answer (score 1):

```
type:  mass
```

Looks like you have some typos there, it should be `maas` at least.